# Is there an easy to import an XML file for which I have an XSD into a SQL database using either C# or SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, xsd

I've tried a few things, first I generated the classes using `xsd.exe` and wrote a quick 3 lines of code to import the xml into the memory in C#. However the XML is pretty complex and there are a considerable number of different types.

I then used xsd2db to create a database that matches the .xsd definition.

I'm looking for an easy way to get the XML into the database, either using entity framework or similar straight from my object, or via some kind of XML import.

I tried using the Import Data function of SQL (presumably it can be automated) but it doesn't support XML, only .CSV or .TXT

Anything pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated, even if you don't have a direct answer.

Comment: Isn´t this what SQLXMLBulkload is suppose to do?

Comment: Quite possibly, I'm afraid I am just a c# developer who has always used SQL in the simplest sense and I have no experience of importing data.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to achieve this task of importing data from an XML file into a SQL Server table.

Import XML data from an XML file into SQL Server table using the OPENROWSET function
Parse the XML data using the OPENXML function

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'easy way' - it depends a lot on what the XSD and XML look like.

The problem is that given a complex XML structure there is not necessarily an obvious corresponding set of SQL tables matching it: the relationships can be hidden or non-obvious, data types do not match exactly etc. Hence automatic tools can (and will) fail often.

I am afraid that the best way would be to look at those XSD / XML and create the target database structure and transfer code manually.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used XmlReader with EntityFramework CodeFirst.

Simple create classes for deserializing from xml (with or without using xsd) and then decorate them with both xml attributes and EF attributes.
Like that:

```
public class School 
{
    [XmlAttribute] //XML Serializer attribute
    [MaxLength(30)] // CodeFirst Data Annotations
    public string Name { get; set;}
    [XmlArray]
    public List<string> Students { get; set; } 
}
```

It will, however, take you some time at first as you need to decorate properly classes to match both XML And table in SQL Server.